# Rendering plain-text or HTML text in TextView

Tags: android

Is it possible for a TextView to dynamically render either a plain-text or a text with HTML content in it?

I have searched for this information but ended up mostly finding solutions 
for formatting the text with HTML content only using `Html.fromHtml()`.

When I try to pass a plain-text to `Html.fromHtml()` it throws a NullPointerException.

```
String terms = "Exclusions apply"
// or String terms = "Exclusions apply <a href="https://www.google.com">See details</a>" 

if (Html.fromHtml(terms) != null)
    mTerms.setText(Html.fromHtml(terms));
else
    mTerms.setText(terms);
```

Comment: It's be more helpful if you could provide the sample `plain-text` or HTML content you'd like to put into the `TextView`.

Comment: Html.fromHtml doesn't throw an NPE no matter what you pass as String (if the String isn't null itself). I'm assuming mTerms is null but since you didn't post your stacktrace or more of your code there's no way to tell. BTW you shouldn't run Html.formHtml twice, it's a very expensive operation.

Comment: Just going to post the same as Emanuel your Html.fromHtml cant throw npe it has no sense to make a null check of it, all looks like your textview is null.

Comment: Thanks Emanuel & Nanoc. It was mTerms which was null and fixed it. It was my mistake :(